# Whar is the usage of the unused parameter "status"?

Tags: c, function, parameters

I don't understand what is the usage of `status` parameter in function

```
void TC0_CH0_TimerInterruptHandler( TC_TIMER_STATUS status , uintptr_t context );
```

Can somebody explain to me why who wrote the code included this *apparently useless* parameter?

```
#include "definitions.h"

static bool volatile bToggleLED = false;

void TC0_CH0_TimerInterruptHandler(TC_TIMER_STATUS status , uintptr_t context)
{
    bToggleLED = true;
}

int main ( void )
{   
    SYS_Initialize(NULL);
    TC0_TimerCallbackRegister( TC0_CH0_TimerInterruptHandler, (uintptr_t)NULL);

    TC0_TimerStart();

    while ( true )
    {
        if ( bToggleLED )
        {
            bToggleLED = false;
            LED_Toggle();
        }
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `TC0_TimerCallbackRegister` is a function that accepts two parameters: `TC_TIMER_STATUS status` and `uintptr_t context`. The `context` is the value that you provided, i.e. `(uintptr_t)NULL`. The code calling your callback will provide a value for the `status`; `TC_TIMER_STATUS` is an `enum` defined [here](https://github.com/Microchip-MPLAB-Harmony/net/blob/b58a7bdd2009911862111ac1a01cadb3b8ac70a8/apps/berkeley_tcp_client/firmware/src/config/sam_e54_xpro/peripheral/tc/plib_tc_common.h#L116).

```
typedef enum
{
    TC_TIMER_STATUS_NONE = 0, 
    /*  overflow */
    TC_TIMER_STATUS_OVERFLOW = TC_INTFLAG_OVF_Msk,

    /* match compare 1 */
    TC_TIMER_STATUS_MATCH1 = TC_INTFLAG_MC1_Msk,
    
    TC_TIMER_STATUS_MSK = TC_TIMER_STATUS_OVERFLOW | TC_TIMER_STATUS_MATCH1, 

    /* Force the compiler to reserve 32-bit memory for enum */
    TC_TIMER_STATUS_INVALID = 0xFFFFFFFF
} TC_TIMER_STATUS;
```

The idea - I believe, as I cannot find the documentation - is that you can check the timer flags to see if the timer had overflown, or matched the counter, or neither happened.

---

The function prototype must match that what is expected, therefore `TC0_CH0_TimerInterruptHandler` needs both arguments even though neither is used.

Answer (score 3):

Even if, in this particular function, `status` parameter is unused, it is something necessary because that function is an *interrupt handler*, or in general something that later is passed as a **function pointer**.

See how in the code it is instantiated: It is the first parameter of `TC0_TimerCallbackRegister` function:

```
TC0_TimerCallbackRegister( TC0_CH0_TimerInterruptHandler, (uintptr_t)NULL);
```

This function is defined with something like

```
TC0_TimerCallbackRegister( void (* fun)(TC_TIMER_STATUS status , uintptr_t context), uintptr_t par)
```

Not only it *expects* a function pointer in the first parameter, but it requires a pointer to a function with that specific signature. That's why `TC0_CH0_TimerInterruptHandler` needs to be defined with status parameter as well: omitting that parameter would have resulted in a compilation error.